# Cannot always launch DevicePolicyManager activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, launch, device-admin

I have some strange problem. When I try to launch DevicePolicyManager activity from my main activity, it loads properly. However, when I make a notification, call QuestionActivity (if user clicks the notification), and then try to call DevicePolicyManager activity from QuestionActivity, I get (logcat):

```
INFO/ActivityManager(104): Starting activity: Intent {
act=android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN
cmp=com.android.settings/.DeviceAdminAdd
(has extras) }
WARN/InputManagerService(104): Window already focused, ignoring focus
gain of:
com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4514a2d0
```

And nothing appears. This is strange for me, cause I'm able to launch different Android OS activity from QuestionActivity:

```
//This works 
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I cannot launch the DevicePolicyManager with:

```
//This works from main activity, but not from QuestionActivity
MyDeviceAdmin admin = new MyDeviceAdmin(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
         admin.getDeviceAdminComponent());
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
            "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 234234234);
```

I would be very grateful for any help, cause I'm completely stuck.

Comment: It turned out, that this activity won't launch when MyDeviceAdmin is active.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, how do you solved it?

Comment: @ROI Hi, Unfortunately I don't remember what we did in the end, but I believe my previous comment includes a tip. You can check if MyDeviceAdmin is active - if it is then you usually don't need to show that view (as the user doesn't have to activate it). And if it's not active then that activity should launch (at least it did in my case).