# how can I call a funtction with parameter is DevicePolicyManager from activity other?

Tags: android, android-activity

There are two activity in my app.

**Activity A**

```
        adminComponent = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this,PermissionReceiver.class);
        policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        if (policyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponent)) {
            lockScreen(policyManager);
        }
```

I can call lockScreen function, It's work fine, but **how can I call this function from Activity B?**
I try this code in **Activity B**

```
DevicePolicyManager policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
lockScreen(policyManager);
```

but I get exception `07-12 22:38:36.939: E/AndroidRuntime(14061): java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10245 for policy #3`

**lockScreen function**

```
public void lockScreen(final DevicePolicyManager aPolicyManager) {
    final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    final Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    final int[] retryCount = new int[] { 0 };

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (powerManager.isScreenOn()&& retryCount[0] <= MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
            aPolicyManager.lockNow();
            //unregisterReceiver(turnOffScreenReciever);
            retryCount[0]++;
            handler.postDelayed(this, RETRY_DELAY * retryCount[0]);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

}

It's similar the question at this link
    [Cannot always launch DevicePolicyManager activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194365/cannot-always-launch-devicepolicymanager-activity-from-another-activity) but I really dont get the final answer. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking more time. Finally, I have a solution flowing this code
From Activity B, I just need do like that

```
policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        adminComponent = new ComponentName(this,PermissionReceiver.class);
        if (policyManager.isAdminActive(adminComponent)) {
            lockScreen(policyManager);
        }
```

It's work fine, thank anyone!